# Replace two joins in one

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've two joins:

```
LEFT JOIN TransactionAmounts AS TAR ON T.orderID = TAR.orderID AND TAR.customerType = 1
LEFT JOIN TransactionAmounts AS TAA ON T.orderID = TAA.orderID AND TAA.customerType = 0
```

How I can replace this two joins for one? For improve performance

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
LEFT JOIN TransactionAmounts AS TAR ON T.orderID = TAR.orderID AND TAP.customerType in(0, 1 )
```

Or

```
LEFT JOIN TransactionAmounts AS TAR ON T.orderID = TAR.orderID AND (TAP.customerType = 0 OR TAP.customerType = 1)
```

Check your execution plan

Comment: But please keep in mind, that the result is NOT the same: usually there is a reason, why you had TAA and TAR... similar to self-joins, you might need certain data from TAA AND TAR. Could you paste the whole query?